# Scala - Create list from for loop

Tags: scala

Is there an easy way to create a list from a for-loop that, in each iteration of the loop, iterates on an iterator?

For example, let's say I have an iterator that returns a random double each time it is called:

```
val randDoubleIterator = new Iterator[Double] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = true
    override def next(): Double = {
        Random.nextDouble
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to create a list of 10 random doubles. I could loop through the iterator to get 10 random doubles, adding each to my list (myList) as I go:

```
// The following is pseudocode
val myList = new List

for (i <- 0 until 10) {
    myList.add(randDoubleIterator.next())
}
```

Is there an easier, more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
List.fill(10)(Random.nextDouble())
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick, even when replacing Random.nextDouble() with a custom Iterator.next() call

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is both easier and more succinct.

```
val randDoubleIterator = Iterator.continually(util.Random.nextDouble)

val myList = randDoubleIterator.take(10).toList
```

This assumes that you want to keep `randDoubleIterator` around for other purposes later in the code.